# Using native code from C language in Java for Programming Microcontroller

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, microcontroller, native-code

I have a **source code library** from [Renesas](https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/products/sensor-products/environmental-sensors/digital-gas-sensors/zmod4410-firmware-configurable-indoor-air-quality-iaq-sensor-embedded-artificial-intelligence-ai) for their Co2 sensor. The source code library is completely written in C language and a **static library** (with *.a* extension) of it is given for the Co2 sensor which was helpful for me to use it in any microcontroller that uses C/C++ language. Even there are a lot of examples of it.

So, I have a microcontroller called DPM5050 which runs in Java programming language. Therefore, I came to know, that it is possible to use the native code in JAVA using JNI (Java Native Interface). I also came to know that to use native source code in Java, I need a dynamic link library. But I only have a static library which is provided by the [Renesas](https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/products/sensor-products/environmental-sensors/digital-gas-sensors/zmod4410-firmware-configurable-indoor-air-quality-iaq-sensor-embedded-artificial-intelligence-ai).

My question is how can I do that using a static library that was given by [Renesas](https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/products/sensor-products/environmental-sensors/digital-gas-sensors/zmod4410-firmware-configurable-indoor-air-quality-iaq-sensor-embedded-artificial-intelligence-ai)?

Can I able to change the static library to the dynamic link library by myself without contacting [Renesas](https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/products/sensor-products/environmental-sensors/digital-gas-sensors/zmod4410-firmware-configurable-indoor-air-quality-iaq-sensor-embedded-artificial-intelligence-ai)?

And how to implement this in Java using JNI to use the native source code library provided by the [Renesas](https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/products/sensor-products/environmental-sensors/digital-gas-sensors/zmod4410-firmware-configurable-indoor-air-quality-iaq-sensor-embedded-artificial-intelligence-ai)?

- Since I just came to know about this JNI technology to use native
  source code in Java. *So, I would also like to ask you to give me
  suggestions or opinions on this topic. And I am also looking for some
  good documentation with examples or tutorials or guidance to proceed
  further.*

Right now, I am reading [Java APIs, Extensions and Libraries: With JavaFX, JDBC, jmod, jlink, Networking, and the Process API - by Kishori Sharan's](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/java-apis-extensions/9781484235461/html/323071_2_En_7_Chapter.xhtml) book in Chapter 7 of this book they have some details about JNI.

I am looking forward to your responses. Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,
Mustaq.

Comment: You write a library of your own that contains functions that you want to be able to call from Java, build it as a shared library and link it against the static library. The functions you wrote in this shared library then call whatever functions it needs in the static library.

Comment: Since, there is no documentation available for the Co2 sensors regarding the registers from their website. I think without this details, i can not write my own library in java.

Comment: On their website, they provided some software package which has some header files for the library that they made and a static library as well.

Comment: This software package also has some examples, like how to use it in different microcontrollers like AVR, ARM, ESP, Raspberry Pi and so on. But all this uses the library which was made with header files and static library files provided by them.

Comment: All the examples provided by them for different microcontrollers uses C/C++ language.

Comment: Java microcontrollers are kind of like cars with square wheels and just one gear. Sure, you can probably use them... but why exactly would you want something that's slow and cumbersome just for the heck of it?

Comment: I agree with your car example. But, as an intern, in my new company. I was asked to configure the display which has its microcontroller with it and this microcontroller runs in Java. So, due to this fact, I had to work on this.